# How to get invoker object in my callback in Java?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I'm trying to walkaround missing [`shouldInterceptRequest(.. request)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)) before android-21. So i'm having only `shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView, java.util.String)`. But when running on android-19 i can see `isMainFrame` property in the invoker that i need to know:

[image]

Unfortunately the invoker does not provide `this` in the invocation so i don't have direct reference. How can i get invoker (`IoThreadClientImpl`) object reference in the method in my listener object (`WebViewClient` to be more detailed)? I believe regular java reflection (or some specific android reflection) should be used.

PS 1. `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` does not suit because it does not provide caller object, class/method/line only.

PS 2. It seems that [setting](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#setSecurityManager(java.lang.SecurityManager)) custom SecurityManager is not the solution since it throws exception..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's impossible in general case but in my case i was able to create proxy for `IoThreadClient` in `AwContents` instance and intercept invocation - if it's my required method `shouldInterceptRequest` with 2 args - i just remember it, then pass invocation to original instance (the required value was not in invoker object but in invocation arguments).

Proxy injection in `WebView` inheritor:

```
private synchronized void initIoThreadClient()
  {
    final Object awContents = ReflectionUtils.extractProperty(this, new String[]
      {
        "mProvider",
        "mAwContents"
      });

    final String ioThreadClientProperty = "mIoThreadClient";
    final Object originalClient = ReflectionUtils.extractProperty(
      awContents,
      new String[]
      {
        ioThreadClientProperty
      });

    // avoid injecting twice (already injected Proxy instance has another class name)
    if (!originalClient.getClass().getSimpleName().startsWith("$Proxy"))
    {
      Object proxyClient = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        originalClient.getClass().getClassLoader(),
        originalClient.getClass().getInterfaces(),
        new IoThreadClientInvocationHandler(originalClient));

      // inject proxy instead of original client
      boolean injected = ReflectionUtils.injectProperty(awContents, ioThreadClientProperty, proxyClient);
      if (injected)
      {
        Integer mNativeAwContents = (Integer) ReflectionUtils.extractProperty(awContents, "mNativeAwContents");
        Object mWebContentsDelegate = ReflectionUtils.extractProperty(awContents, "mWebContentsDelegate");
        Object mContentsClientBridge = ReflectionUtils.extractProperty(awContents, "mContentsClientBridge");
        Object mInterceptNavigationDelegate = ReflectionUtils.extractProperty(awContents, "mInterceptNavigationDelegate");

        boolean invoked = ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(awContents, "nativeSetJavaPeers", new Object[]
          {
            mNativeAwContents, awContents, mWebContentsDelegate,
            mContentsClientBridge, proxyClient, mInterceptNavigationDelegate
          });
        if (!invoked)
        {
          e("Failed to inject IoThreadClient proxy");
        }
      }
    }
```

IoThreadClientInvocationHandler class:

```
public class IoThreadClientInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler
{
  private final String TAG = Utils.getTag(IoThreadClientInvocationHandler.class);

  public static transient Boolean isMainFrame;
  private Object wrappedObject;

  public IoThreadClientInvocationHandler(Object wrappedObject)
  {
    this.wrappedObject = wrappedObject;
  }

  @Override
  public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable
  {
    // intercept invocation and store 'isMainFrame' argument
    if (method.getName().startsWith("shouldInterceptRequest") && args.length == 2)
    {
      String url = (String)args[0];
      isMainFrame = (Boolean)args[1];

      Log.d(TAG, "isMainFrame=" + isMainFrame + " for " + url);
    }
    return method.invoke(wrappedObject, args);
  }
}
```

ReflectionUtils class:

```
public class ReflectionUtils
{
  public static Object extractProperty(Object target, String field)
  {
    return extractProperty(target, target.getClass(), field);
  }

  public static Object extractProperty(Object target, Class clazz, String field)
  {
    try
    {
      Field f = clazz.getDeclaredField(field);
      if (!f.isAccessible())
      {
        f.setAccessible(true);
      }
      return f.get(target);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
    {
      return extractProperty(target, clazz.getSuperclass(), field);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      return null;
    }
  }

  public static Object extractProperty(Object target, String []fields)
  {
    Object eachTarget = target;
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
    {
      eachTarget = extractProperty(eachTarget, eachTarget.getClass(), fields[i]);
      if (eachTarget == null)
      {
        return null;
      }
    }
    return eachTarget;
  }

  public static boolean injectProperty(Object target, String field, Object value)
  {
    try
    {
      Field f = target.getClass().getDeclaredField(field);
      if (!f.isAccessible())
      {
        f.setAccessible(true);
      }
      f.set(target, value);
      return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public static boolean invokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, Object[] args)
  {
    Method[] methods = target.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method eachMethod : methods)
    {
      if (eachMethod.getName().equals(methodName))
      {
        try
        {
          if (!eachMethod.isAccessible())
          {
            eachMethod.setAccessible(true);
          }
          eachMethod.invoke(target, args);
          return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```